# Could not run the react-native application

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I am getting this error while installing application.

More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'

Comment: Could you please share your react-native version and if have ```packagingOptions``` of your app level build.gradle file

Comment: React-native version : 0.61.2...project does not have packagingOptions

Comment: Then please try by adding below ``` android { 
 ........
 packagingOptions {
        pickFirst '**/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst '**/x86/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst '**/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst '**/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst '**/x86/libjsc.so'
        pickFirst '**/armeabi-v7a/libjsc.so'
    }
 }``` to your app level build.gradle file

Comment: Ok...It's working

Comment: Glad to help you .So then I'll put this as the answer and then you can mark as correct and give a vote up for me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add below to your app level build.gradle file in side the android tag

```
 android{
    ........

    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst '**/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst '**/x86/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst '**/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst '**/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst '**/x86/libjsc.so'
        pickFirst '**/armeabi-v7a/libjsc.so'
    }
  }
```